# Visual Studio 2013 opens every project in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've recently upgraded to VS2013 and I've noticed that it has the annoying habit of expanding every project node in Solution Explorer.

I can go through and close all of the nodes I'm not working on at the moment to declutter the display, but every time I open up the solution it re-clutters it by opening each project node again.

Anybody know any tricks to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see. It was a corrupt suo file. I just deleted it and all was well.